# Как корректно отобразить большое количество однотипных элементов в QML

Tags: javascript, qml

Мое понимание qml не такое глубокое, поэтому столкнулся с проблемой. Есть интерфейс, который предполагает большого количества элементов ввода со стороны, расположенных строго друг за другом. Элементы ввода могут отличаться друг от друга, но в большинстве встречаются элементы одного типа. Для реализации этого я воспользовался ListModel и ListView, запихнув внутрь ListModel элементы состояния. Например,

```
ListModel {
   id: main_model
   ListElement {
      description: qsTr("Title1")
      json_id: "ip_addr"
      input_method: "base"
      value: "172.*.*.*"
      regular_expression: ""
   }
   ListElement {
      description: qsTr("Title2")
      input_method: "drop_select"
      all_values: []
      regular_expression: ""
      json_id: "ik_id"
      value: ""
      id_of_group: "ik_settings"
   }
}
```

В записимости от input_method, delegate в ListView с помощью Loader использует нужный элемент.

Вот компонент который находится в Loader

```
Component {
   id: drop_select
   Elements.DropMenu {
      x: raw.width - width
      width: 161
      height: 40
      readOnly: true
      model: all_values
      selectedValue: value
      onValueChanged: (newValue) => { configs[json_id] = newValue; print(json_id, configs[json_id]) }
   }
}
```

Где value и all_values - это свойства из ListView. Для других типов могут использоваться другие свойства. Проблема - не со всеми value и all_values,к примеру, это работает. Например, не могу поменять динамически состояние для value типа bool или list ([1,2,3,4] - например).
Для динамического изменения используется:

```
    function setValue(configName, value){
        for (let ind1 = 0; ind1 < main_model.count; ind1++){
            let mainEl = main_model.get(ind1)
            if (mainEl.json_id === configName){
                mainEl.value = value
            }
        }
    }
```

Вопрос: правильный ли мой подход к получению большого числа однотипных элементов? Если нет, подскажите, каким образом это лучше реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам необходимо отображать в списке элементы управления разных типов, то следует использовать DelegateChooser. Для отображения большого количества элементов рекомендуется использовать ListView или Repeater.

В ответе на данный вопрос имеется пример, который должен помочь и вам
[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340572/%D0%A3-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-qlistsome-object-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81/1355554#1355554)